# test containers not working in spring boot and getting following exception org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException:

Tags: spring, kotlin, unit-testing, testcontainers

I have implemented test containers in kotlin spring boot project but when I run project I am getting following exception

```
org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Failed to resolve parameter [bootiful.kotlin.CustomerRepository customerRepository] in constructor [public bootiful.kotlin.KotlinApplicationTests(bootiful.kotlin.CustomerRepository)]: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@55fb36de testClass = bootiful.kotlin.KotlinApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [bootiful.kotlin.KotlinApplication, bootiful.kotlin.CustomerRepository], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnectionContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@a4ca3f6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@b6b1987, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7c541c15, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3f0846c6, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@3e10dc6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5de402fc], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameter(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:159)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ParameterResolutionUtils.resolveParameters(ParameterResolutionUtils.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:59)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [ReactiveWebMergedContextConfiguration@55fb36de testClass = bootiful.kotlin.KotlinApplicationTests, locations = [], classes = [bootiful.kotlin.KotlinApplication, bootiful.kotlin.CustomerRepository], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnectionContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@1f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@a4ca3f6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@b6b1987, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@7c541c15, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@3f0846c6, org.springframework.boot.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClientContextCustomizer@3e10dc6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@5de402fc], contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
```

below my application.properties in kotlin folder

```
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres
spring.r2dbc.username=postgres
spring.r2dbc.password=postgres
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

below application.properties in my test folder

```
spring.sql.init.mode=always
spring.r2dbc.url=r2dbc:tc:postgresql:///customers?TC_IMAGE_TAG=13.3
```

below my KotlinTest class

```
@SpringBootTest
class KotlinApplicationTests(@Autowired val customerRepository: CustomerRepository) {

    @Test
    fun contextLoads() {
   runBlocking {

       customerRepository.save(Customer(null, "Hadi"))
       val customers = customerRepository.findAll()
       Assertions.assertNotNull(customers.last().id)
       Assertions.assertEquals(customers.count(), 6)
   }



    }

}

below TestContainers

class TestKotlinApplication {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection
    fun postgresContainer(): PostgreSQLContainer<*> {
        return PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:latest")
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fromApplication<KotlinApplication>().with(TestKotlinApplication::class).run(*args)
}
```

My KotlinApplication.kt class

```
 @SpringBootApplication
    class KotlinApplication
    
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<KotlinApplication>(*args)
    }
    
    interface CustomerRepository:CoroutineCrudRepository<Customer,Int>{
    
    }
    
    data class Customer(@Id val id: Int?, val name:String){
    
    }
```

below my build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.1.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.2"
    id("org.graalvm.buildtools.native") version "0.9.23"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.20"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.20"
}

group = "bootiful"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:r2dbc-postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-testcontainers")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.testcontainers:r2dbc")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake

Comment: I don't see any code that initializes testcontainers. Do you have it?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I have added initialized test container class please check it

Comment: You are missing the call of `PostgreSQLContainer.start()` method

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko where I have to call that method

Comment: in your `@Bean` method. `return PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:latest").apply { start() }`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko I am still getting error above I have applied as you told me but it did not solve issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254731/discussion-between-edgar-and-nikolai-shevchenko).

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko what do you think any other problem in my code or setup

Comment: To know more about it please share a minimal example that reproduces the issue. We need to see the dependencies in your maven/gradle project too. Please, share a github repository and not only snippets in the future.

Comment: @EddúMeléndez thank you for  I am posting my full stack exception as well I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by installing docker to my windows 10 and running docker in IntelliJ idea